# Facebook Graph API User search doesn't show all user with the name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used the following Graph API Search: search?type=user&q="keren sereno"

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?fields=picture.height%2875%29.width%2875%29&type=user&q=%22Keren+Sereno%22&format=json&access_token=CAADUw5iRRFgBAHc7122VQAowuxc508Qfu9LHXmQ7JUu08N9bqI8ZBBlZChUxUa8ohkgUJgrxHrqAEtHZCVmyEHfWlFSpcy8PkfeXEJHhZBzZCfOF48dxMr2K6MclHRZCv4cWxzAIZAcQ8PJEBxyfN2N895YTi3KL69xtZAESFcwlNtp3FZAZA73s6dzzcWPypK2m5Fzalr0QbQniLjVzrZB3TMe&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AeyvcQVykHYerDcG3HJclGsQVXjwbEG_8vpHj9Msd4uCLgIks-MSWtHoB3JwtET0q4ZeNFmgPZNvHRsWAxf1vfqT

and got the following results:

```
"data": 

"name": "Keren Sereno", 
"id": "10152843625991047"

"name": "Keren Sereno", 
"id": "1518053371790859"
```

but i didn't get the following result http://graph.facebook.com/100000321541242

"id": "100000321541242",
"first_name": "Keren",
"gender": "female",
"last_name": "Sereno",
"locale": "he_IL",
"name": "Keren Sereno",
"username": "keren.sereno"

can anybody help me please?

Comment: Search is simply not guaranteed to return “everything”.

Comment: v2.6 same problem here